# Reselect reused selector unexpected behaivor

Tags: javascript, react-redux, reselect

The context is a React app with reselect and redux, however my problem might just be 'pure' JS. My problem is that I can't understand why I can't reuse a selector.

I have a selector `X`. In addition, I have a makeGetX as follows:

```
const X = createSelector( [...], (// checks for a specific flag and manipulates)=> x );
const makeGetX = () => X;
```

Some of my components simply use X and some the maker.
Before that I used to only have maker with the X definition:

```
const makeGetX = () => createSelector( [...], (// checks for a specific flag and manipulates)=> x );
```

The former worked great whenever the specific aforementioned feature was used.
Refactoring it as shown in the first snippet breaks (infinite updates) it whenever I use the maker.

The context of use is I have multiple components using a `makeMapStateToProps` and within it

```
...
const getX = makeGetX()
...
return (state,ownProps) => ({..., X: getX(state, ownProps), ...});
```

And in my connect function I call `makeMapStateToProps`.

For now I solved it by duplicating the code :( in both definitions.

Would appreciate any insight or explanation.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any Immutable Data Structure library?

Comment: Could you share some codesandbox link? It'll clarify your questions and will help to get appropriate answer.

Comment: @IvanBurnaev RE:  Immutable Data Structure library - no, simple desturcturing or creating new array/objects.
Would try to reproduce in a sandbox, thou might be tricky and take a while :) thanks!

Comment: True, and then in the `getX` in the `makeMapStateToProps` where I use `makeGetX` I invoke it

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! I've missed the call of `createSelector`. Removing my previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess you are calling `createSelector` internally multiple times.
So it returns you different function objects which has a dedicated `memo` storage inside of it.
That's why `shallow` check fails (`connect` is doing simple `shallow-equal` check under the hood).

Comment: Thanks, might be it. After I can verify it I can accept your answer. Thank you